# Enable History Logging In TCSH Shell

Tags: unix, shell, solaris, tcsh

How can I enable logging of all the commands entered in the tcsh shell?

I've tried:

1. Setting the $history variable to 100.
2. The $savehist to 99.
3. Set the $histfile to $home/.history

Typing commands into the shell doesn't save the commands in the history file.

Comment: Is tcsh your login shell ? Where did you set these variables ?

Comment: In $home/.cshrc. My shell doesn't seem to process .tcshrc. It is not my log in shell.

Comment: Only a login tcsh will save history on histfile at logout, as documented in the manual page.

Comment: To launch it as a login shell: tcsh -l

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my .tcshrc:

```
set history=2000
set savehist=(2000 merge)
```